# Define several message listeners in separate context files

Tags: spring, jms

I have defined a **JMS** **listener-container** in my **context.xml** like so :

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="auto" destination-type="topic" >
    <jms:listener id="listener" destination="${jms_topic}" ref="jmsListener" method="onMessage"  />
</jms:listener-container>
```

I have a **integration test suite** in which I enrich my spring context with test specific  beans and logic. Obviously, I don't want to mess my code with this, so I declare them within a **spearate Spring context**, that includes the former one.

Something like :

```
<!-- Import regular configuration -->
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/context.xml"/>

<!-- Test only listener -->
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="auto" destination-type="topic" >
     <jms:listener id="listenerIT" destination="${another_topic}" ref="jmsListenerIT" method="onMessage"  />
</jms:listener-container>
```

As you see, the integration test context declares a new listener container.

The problem is that, whenever I do that, **the former (regular one) is ignored.** As if the last declaration of listener overrides the previous ones.

What is the correct way of declaring several listeners in several files ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a first (partial) solution :
It works if I define and use another connection factory for integration tests.

Comment: I have the same trouble: we have a lot of java modules which contribute to the jms listener container. So your "partial solution" does not work for me. Haven't you find out how to really split declaration over multiple context  files?